# mysql real escape string with LIKE not fetching any result

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a mysql query

```
mysql_query("SELECT name,symbol FROM scode WHERE change='$change' 
AND product='$product' AND series='$typeo' 
AND (name LIKE '%$check%' OR symbol LIKE '%$check%') LIMIT 5");
```

It works Perfectly but If I try to use the same query using mysql string then query is not returning any result.
i tried like this

```
$query= sprintf("SELECT name,symbol FROM `scode` WHERE change='%s' 
AND product='%s' AND series='%s' AND (name LIKE '%s' OR symbol LIKE '%s') 
LIMIT 5",
mysql_real_escape_string($change),
mysql_real_escape_string($product),
mysql_real_escape_string($typeo),
mysql_real_escape_string($check),
mysql_real_escape_string($check));

$fetch= mysql_query($query);
```

How can I make the query that will work? Can some help me? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't actually shown us what either query looks like.

Comment: ever heard of splitting code in multiple lines? how it is supposed to be read? by scrolling for a mile?

Comment: @JellyBelly no error just query is not returning any result.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel sorry for the problem editing the post

Comment: Try printing `$query` after running it through your `sprintf()` call, and see what it looks like. Compare it with the working version of the query, and you'll see what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well no it wouldn't work, because in the first you do a `LIKE %term%`, in the second you do a `LIKE term`. Try adding `%%` around, like this:

```
$query= sprintf("SELECT name,symbol FROM `scode` WHERE change='%s' AND product='%s' AND series='%s' AND (name LIKE '%%%s%%' OR symbol LIKE '%%%s%%') LIMIT 5",mysql_real_escape_string($change),mysql_real_escape_string($product),mysql_real_escape_string($typeo),mysql_real_escape_string($check),mysql_real_escape_string($check));

$fetch= mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the end of your mysql_query and it will show you what the error message is

```
  $fetch= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it and found one issue. Looks like mysql trying to parse "change" column as a keyword. Try to put "change" in ``.